# Which version of hadoop-aws should I use

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I'm running spark jobs on Yarn on EMR 5.14 (hadoop 2.8.3).

Can I use a superior version of hadoop-aws (e.g. 2.9 or 3.1) to benefit from recent optimization in s3a protocol ?

Comment: If you bundle a newer version as part of your Spark apps, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stick with whatever EMR give you. Their s3:// connector is the one which AWS develop and probably your safest option.

FWIW, s3a since in 2.8.3 for input performance. hasn't changed much from later versions, except in 3.1 if you leave `fs.s3a.experimental.fadvise` to `normal`, it automatically switches from optimising for sequential IO to random IO (columnar data) on the first backward seek. Still best to set that property to `random` from the outset if you know all your data is stored as Parquet/ORC in a seekable compression format (i.e. not gzip). No  speedup in writes either. You get a consistency layer equivalent to "consistent EMR" in Hadoop 2.9+, and a high performance output committer in Hadoop 3.1. But you cannot try and use those features by dropping in the later JARs. it will only give you stack traces

Comment: you can't split gzip, so can't have >1 worker process a single parquet file, no matter how big it is